# When using full join in SQL, the join result didn't display the null value

Tags: sql, join

I try to full join two table in SQL, and the result expected should display those NULL values, but it haven't displayed at all.
two tables look like this

[first table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DEKi.png)
[part of second table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN9CE.png)

```
SELECT *
FROM clinics
    FULL JOIN participants
    USING (clinic_id)
WHERE partic_id=NULL OR location_cat=NULL OR (clinic_id=NULL AND location_cat=NULL)
```

Those are my code, and the result expected should have values in it, but now there happened to have some problems. Could someone help me on that?

Comment: What is your actual database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: Compare NULL always with IS:  `partic_id IS NULL`

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#285557)

Comment: Actual database it's MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM clinics FULL JOIN participants
    ON clinics.clinic_id = participants.clinic_id
WHERE participants.partic_id IS NULL OR clinics.location_cat IS NULL
   OR (clinics.clinic_id IS NULL AND clinics.location_cat IS NULL)
```

This query should return all rows from both tables where either the partic_id column in the participants table is NULL, the location_cat column in the clinics table is NULL, or both the clinic_id and location_cat columns in the clinics table are NULL. Any rows that do not satisfy these conditions will not be included in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Null is not a value, and so you must use `IS NULL` instead of `= (equal to)`

```
SELECT *
FROM clinics
    FULL JOIN participants
    USING (clinic_id)
WHERE partic_id is NULL OR location_cat is NULL OR (clinic_id is NULL AND location_cat is NULL)
```

Comment: still it doesn't work, i think the problem is on the full join things.